# Why isn't Laravel timing out?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8.x on Windows 10 and am developing a CRUD that uses Vuetify on a Vue component that is trying to display the data in a small array of objects - just 11 items with four fields each - in a v-data-table. Most of the functionality is working now and I'm just doing the last bits of the code.

Everything has been going fine for several days but something has gone very wrong tonight. I changed a line or two of code, let `npm run watch` recompile the module I changed and hit refresh on my browser to see if the changes are working better than the original code. The refresh happened an hour and a half ago and I'm STILL waiting for it to render something!

It shows no sign of ending and I can't find any error messages anywhere. Apparently something is seriously wrong even though I've only changed a couple of lines of code. I'm completely baffled. I've never touched the default timeout settings and, honestly, don't even know where they are.

I *have* had timeouts before, in fact I manage to have two or three a day. For no reason I know, the first refresh after I've been away from the computer for an hour or two will tend to timeout while subsequent ones will go very quickly and let me get back to work coding. When I do get a timeout, the message says the timeout happened after 60 seconds. Of course that is not elapsed time - elapsed time is more like 5 to 10 minutes - but surely my current process should have timed out long ago.

Why am I getting timeouts when I get them? Why am I NOT getting one despite my last refresh having been over 90 minutes ago now? I should mention that I've rebooted the entire computer and even that did not help.

How can I get Laravel working better?

### Update

As per Maarten's suggestion, I've reverted my code. Well, not exactly reverted it but it solved the problem. I had this:

```
deleteRow() {
      this.deleteRowFlag = false;
      this.deleteMessage = "Task deleted";
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deleteID: " + this.deleteID); 
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deleteDescription: " + this.deleteDescription);
          
      var index = -1;    
      for (let todo of this.todos) {
         if (todo.id == deleteID) index = todo.index;
       }

      // const index = this.todos.indexOf(this.deleteDescription);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - index: " + index);
      var deletedItemsArray = this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deletedItemsArray.length: " + deletedItemsArray.length);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deletedItemsArray[0].id: " + deletedItemsArray[0].id);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deletedItemsArray[0].description: " + deletedItemsArray[0].description);
      //FIX: Isn't actually deleting the row!
      this.showDeleteSnackbar = true;
    },
```

I couldn't imagine any of that being a problem and the little for loop was the last thing I added so I simply commented it out like so:

```
deleteRow() {
      this.deleteRowFlag = false;
      this.deleteMessage = "Task deleted";
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deleteID: " + this.deleteID); 
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deleteDescription: " + this.deleteDescription);
          
      // var index = -1;    
      // for (let todo of this.todos) {
      //   if (todo.id == deleteID) index = todo.index;
      // }

      // const index = this.todos.indexOf(this.deleteDescription);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - index: " + index);
      var deletedItemsArray = this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deletedItemsArray.length: " + deletedItemsArray.length);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deletedItemsArray[0].id: " + deletedItemsArray[0].id);
      console.log(this.name + ".deleteRow() - deletedItemsArray[0].description: " + deletedItemsArray[0].description);
      //FIX: Isn't actually deleting the row!
      this.showDeleteSnackbar = true;
    },
```

I gave `npm run watch` a moment to compile the code, cloned the browser window, and refreshed. This time, the page rendered immediately. It looks as if I created an infinite loop and Laravel apparently failed to detect it and shut it down! I am astonished. I thought all professional development software for decades monitored for that kind of thing at compile time and execution time. I've been coding for multiple decades and I haven't seen a runaway loop since very early in my coding days.

I can see immediately that I need a `this` in front of deletedID in the loop. I'm surprised that the compiler didn't jump on that! (Actually, I think the logic still wouldn't work with that change so I'm going to take a few minutes to relearn how to manipulate arrays of objects in Javascript.)

As for the network tab in the browser, there was nothing in it. There was nothing in most of the tabs. And there was nothing in the `npm run watch` terminal window after I'd written the bad code.

Comment: Few questions: 1) does it work when you revert your code changes? 2) does not watch compile correctly, any errors there? 3) Look into the network tab of your browser and see if the network is taking a long time or not.

Comment: @Maarten Veerman - I've updated the question with new information as per your remarks. Thanks for helping me fix it but I'm still surprised that the compiler allowed the code I wrote and that the execution environment failed to shut it down.

Comment: The fact that the compiler allowed the code depends on the settings given to the compiler. Personally I always code my frontend as separate as possible from backend, so I'm often using a pure Vue config. This allows me to better set specific es-lint options, and surely that would have caught the uninitiated deleteID. Also note that your problem has nothing to do with Laravel, it's completely JavaScript/npm based. Maybe the npm watch settings are provided by a Laravel default setting, but that doesn't mean it's Laravel code.

Comment: @Maarten Veerman - I don't understand why the browser failed to react. The refresh in the browser literally ran all night and showed no signs of ever stopping. The compile had finished in the normal time. If Laravel had no responsibility in this situation, shouldn't the browser have noticed that something was badly off?